# Matrix Linear Transformation that is Angle Preserving

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose $T:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is a linear transformation whose relative angle measures are preserved and whose transformation is a rigid motion. That is, given any nonzero vectors $v,u\in\mathbb R^2$, the angle between $T(v)$ and $T(u)$ is the same as the angle between $v$ and $u$, and $|T(v)T(u)|=|vu|$ with preserved orientation.

What I've done is take the dot product of the original vectors and their transformations, and computed their angles with an arccosine function. From there I believe I found the properties needed for the transformation to preserve angles, which are: $$T(v)\cdot T(u)=v\cdot u \\ \Vert T(v)\Vert = \Vert v\Vert$$

If these properties hold, then the transformation $T$ is a rigid transformation that rotates every vector in the vector space. Is this correct?

Comment: $T$ could also be a reflection, and it could also scale vectors uniformly.

Comment: So then I need another property that makes T orientation preserving as well?

Comment: Yes, and one that makes $T$ preserve lengths

Comment: Hmm. So for orientation to stay the same, the transformation matrix needs to have determinant positive 1 only, and for length to be preserved the inverse of the matrix needs to equal its transpose?

Comment: Is $T$ necessarily a linear transformation in this context? If so, then you should specify this in your question. If not, then you also have to account for the possibility of translations.

Comment: Any **linear** transformation $T$ with positive determinant will preserve orientation. It turns out that if such a transformation $T$ preserves angles and has determinant $1$, then it will be a rotation.

Comment: Oh that's right. Fixing that right now